# how to run a vue js 2 app with pm2 library in linux(RHEL)?

Tags: linux, vue.js, pm2

I have a vue js app, which i run it locally with npm run serve command.
I am trying to run it in a development linux ( RHEL) box with pm2 library, but it doesn't start the application. how exactly to configure my project to run with pm2? my package.son file is below

```json
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts":{
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: You have 3 serve commands. You won't be able to run the app, with or without pm2.

Comment: I'm not sure, but this question may maybe help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51875055/how-to-run-nuxt-under-pm2 (even if it's related to Nuxt2)

Comment: @kissu - i found something similar for react , but not for vue , i don't know if same thing works. in react, i can do npx pm2 npm start --name "appname" -- start

Comment: PM2 executes Node.js scripts - it can't execute an SPA as it is supposed to run inside your browser. Instead of PM2 you need nginX or Apache to serve the bunch on JavaScript files to the browser.

Comment: @IVOGELOV - thanks. this is just for my understanding, I can run npm run serve locally and then go to localhost and access the pages/site. I know we cannot  use this for production , but how does it work when we can access the web pages/application when we just use npm run serve

Comment: NPM runs the package `webpack-dev-server` which starts a simple HTTP server on your computer (usually bound to port 8080). If you want to see the files on this HTTP server you can navigate to `https://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server` (don't add a trailing slash)

Comment: does this answer your question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131881/can-we-use-pm2-to-start-the-development-server-of-vue-cli